# Shell script to check whether the mounted path given in fstab/mtab is valid

Tags: shell, mount

I have mounted several windows machine in Linux machine through fstab.

Eg:

```
*//vmdevmachine/sharedfolder /var/lib/jenkins/Windows/ cifs 
gid=users,file_mode=0664,dir_mode=0775,auto,username=user_name,password=password123*
```

I have few jobs to run, that are dependent on mounted machines like this.

**My requirement**: Before running the job I need (shell script) to check whether the mounted file/directory is valid/exist or not.

i.e from the above example, it need to check whether `**//vmdevmachine/sharedfolder**` exist or not.

Thanks,
-Rajiv

Answer (score 0):

If the directory is mounted currently and does not have a link such as a symlink to it I generally use something like the below.

```
if [ ! -d "/var/lib/jenkins/Windows/" ]; then
    exit $? # The script will exit with exit status from If statement.
fi
```

If the directory (-d) does not exist (!) then exit with the exit code from the if statement. If you are going to be doing multiple directories may want to put them in an array and iterate through them quick like so

```
    files=( "/var/lib/jenkins/Windows/" "/var/lib/jenkins/Windows/2" "/var/lib/jenkins/Windows/3" )

for i in "${files[@]}"
do
    if [ ! -d "$i" ]; then
        exit $? # The script will exit with exit status from If statement.
        fi
done
```

In the above for loop example $i will be the directory during each instance of the for loop. I hope this helps you out as I am still getting used to posting here.